# Why can I not import this class? I don't see how it's a circular import

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, variables, import

I've been driving myself crazy with this issue, and can not figure out what's going on.

As you can see below in my Display.py file, I'm attempting to import a class called 'Location' from my gameworld.py file.

However every time I try to run my game, I get an error stating 'Location is not defined.' What's going on that would cause this?

Why would the exact same import work in one file but not this one?

Display.py

```
from gameworld import *    #I've also tried importing Location directly
screenSize(1500, 800)


bgLocation = Location('introd')

def bgChange():
    bg = bgLocation.room.background
    setBackgroundImage(bg)
    updateDisplay()
```

gameworld.py

```
from Display import *
from output import *

class Room:

    def __init__(self, name, description, exits, actions, roominv, roomkey, lock, background):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.exits = exits
        self.actions = actions
        self.roominv = roominv
        self.roomkey = roomkey
        self.lock = lock
        self.background = background


class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health


class Location:

    def __init__(self, room):
        self.room = world[room]

    def travel(self, direction, bag):
        if direction not in self.room.exits:
            self.no_exit()
        else:
            self.set_new_room_name(direction, bag)
```

For context, the import worked fine in the file below! What's different?

```
from gameworld import *
from Display import *
from output import *
from audio import *

def main():

    player = Player("Jeff", 100)
    bag = Bag([])
    location = Location('introd')

    command = '  '
    while True:
        command = textBoxInput(wordBox)
        if command in location.room.exits:
            location.travel(command, bag)
```

Comment: Gameworld imports Display, and Display imports Gameworld. That's a circular dependency. You can't have 2 files importing each other. In your last example, neither of the other files import main, so there's no circular dependency. Fixing this requires reorganizing your files.

Comment: I suspect these issues are only going to get worse for you. You have `Display` being imported into `gameworld` and vice versa, which indicates an issue with the logic in how you're organising these modules. Using `import *` is not good practice because you no longer know what's in the namespace of any script

Comment: I'm not sure I can see the reason you need `from Display import *` in `gameworld`. Does removing that import solve your issue?

Comment: @roganjosh It's for one specific function that I didn't include in these examples. I think that I can solve the problem by moving the function to a different file though. Thanks!

Comment: @SchrodingersStat however you end up refactoring your code, I really suggest you take note about getting rid of the `import *` approach. As soon as your code gets to any appreciable size, you'll end up trampling your own names are odd parts in the code, which will be tough to debug.

Comment: @roganjosh I'll keep that in mind, gonna start converting some stuff to the regular **import** now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, things like def, class, and import are statements too.

Modules are executed during import, and new functions and classes won’t appear in the module’s namespace until the def (or class) statement has been executed.

This has some interesting implications if you’re doing recursive imports.

Consider a module X which imports module Y and then defines a function called spam:

```
# module X

import Y

def spam():
    print "function in module x"
```

If you import X from your main program, Python will load the code for X and execute it. When Python reaches the import Y statement, it loads the code for Y, and starts executing it instead.

At this time, Python has installed module objects for both X and Y in sys.modules. But X doesn’t contain anything yet; the def spam statement hasn’t been executed.

Now, if Y imports X (a recursive import), it’ll get back a reference to an empty X module object. Any attempt to access the X.spam function on the module level will fail.

```
# module Y

from X import spam # doesn't work: spam isn't defined yet!
```

Note that you don’t have to use from-import to get into trouble:

```
# module Y

import X

X.spam() # doesn't work either: spam isn't defined yet!
```

To fix this, either refactor your program to avoid circular imports (moving stuff to a separate module often helps), or move the imports to the end of the module (in this case, if you move import Y to the end of module X, everything will work just fine).

Hope this helps.